# Codeigniter custom library or other solution?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am updating a persistent login process that I have used on a few other sites to work with codeigniter and wanted to get some opinions on the best way to handle this situation or if there is something that I may be overlooking.

What I have come up with so far is to extend the controller class to determine if the user has already logged in (using codeigniters session library), then if the user has not logged in I look to determine if they have a persistent cookie stored on their machine. If they do then I go through the process of logging the user in with their temp password (along with resetting the temp password and re-creating their persistent cookie for security reasons). This is all good.

Now my question pertains to proper structure and code re-usability. Some of the same functions used in the process described above will also be needed whenever the users logs in by clicking the login button. At the moment my solution for this is to create a custom library that will contain all of the functions associated with user authentication/registration/persistent logins/log ins/log outs, and then call that library from the various places where it's functions will be needed.

The thing that's throwing up a red flag to me though, and why I'm drafting this right now is that within this library I will need to make calls to various models to manipulate/obtain data. I know this is possible...but would it be considered a bad practice to do so? Is there possibly a solution to this scenario that I am missing?

Comment: Very much so. I have accepted it as the answer to my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perfectly fine to call other libraries and models within your own custom library. However, to call and set models/libraries, you can't use the normal `$this` (i.e. this->load->model('some-model')) within a library.

You need to use `$CI`. To do so, set the variable at the beginning of your function (from what I recall, this must be in your function - not the construct). Then you can call models/libraries much the same way you would in a controller. Example:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login_auth {

    function __construct() {

    }

    function run() {

        $CI =& get_instance();  

        $CI->load->model('some-model');
        $CI->load->library('some-library');

        ....

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not bad practice at all to manipulate and obtain data through a library. A library is sort of free reign over codeigniter, and it's meant to be plug and play so your able to make use of all codeigniters functions from within it.